# Replacing ACF with my own code while building WP template

Tags: wordpress, acfpro

Is it possible, in your opinion, to code my own code so I could:
1. upload images in the WP backend interface. 
2. attach that images to a specific post types ?

Also, I would like to replace repeater fields in option page with my own code.

Comment: Of course, time permitting. What is your reason for this?

Comment: As I proceed on building my WP template, I tend  not to be dependent on ACF pro. Currently, when I install my theme on new local sever, some of the data is not shown. That is because, I have not installed ACF on that WP installation. I wish to be independent on ACF.

Comment: You can import/export the DB data: https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-migrate-db-pro/ This is a good alternative for Meta Box creation: https://metabox.io/

Comment: can i replace acf with meta boxes ? can i attach images to post types using meta boxes ?

Comment: import/export the db still requires users to install acf pro. despite importing db he will still need to install acf pro. dont u agree ?

Comment: Yes, is the answer to your above questions.

Comment: David, what did you mean by "time permitting" ? what is it ?

Comment: You can code anything you want, if your time frame allows you to. ACF is a fantastic plugin, to code something like that from scratch would take a very long time. - How valuable is your time.

Comment: i understand. you are right

Comment: David, I have just found answer to my prayer........ add_menu_page()

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to replace ACF option page with a simple WP function, that will create a new admin menu page. Thus, there is no need to ask the end user to purchase ACF pro in order to install my new WP theme. In the new admin menu page, it's possible to build a HTML Bootstrap posting Form. that WP function is called : add_menu_page().